# How to use Linux-specific APIs and libraries only on Linux builds with CMake?

Tags: c, linux, macos, cross-platform, cmake

I have a project that I run on Linux (primarily), but sometimes on Darwin/Mac OS X. I use CMake to generate Makefiles on Linux and an Xcode project on Mac OS X. So far, this has worked well.

Now I want to use some Linux-specific functions (`clock_gettime()` and related functions). I get linker errors on Mac OS X when I try to use `clock_gettime()`, so I assume it is only available on Linux. I am prepared to introduce conditionally-compiled code in the .c files to use `clock_gettime()` on Linux and plain old `clock()` on Mac OS. (BTW I was planning to use `#include <unistd.h>` and `#if _POSIX_TIMERS > 0` as the preprocessor expression, unless someone has a better alternative.)

Things get tricky when it comes to the CMakeLists.txt file. What is the preferred way of introducing linkage to Linux-specific APIs only under the Linux build in a cross-platform CMake project?

Note: An earlier revision of this question contained references to glibc, which was overly specific and confusing. The question is really about the right way to use Linux-specific APIs and libraries in a cross-platform CMake project.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. `clock_gettime` is part of POSIX and should be available on any modern conformant operating system.

Comment: @R.., I tried to use `clock_gettime()` on Mac OS X and I get linker errors (question edited accordingly). Am I missing something?

Comment: @R..: It's part of a POSIX extension.

Comment: @RandallCook, note that since `clock_gettime` requires `-lrt` on Linux, it might require some sort of flags on OS X as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Abstracting away from your examples, and answering only this question:

> How to use Linux-specific APIs and libraries only on Linux builds with
>   CMake?

CMake provides [numerous useful constants](http://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables#System_.26_Compiler_Information) that you can check in order to determine which system you are running:

```
if (${UNIX})
  # *nix-specific includes or actions
elsif (${WIN32})
  # Windows-specific includes or actions
elsif (${APPLE})
  # ...
endif (${UNIX})
```

Comment: Thanks, @sleepy. This is pretty close to what I was looking for. I ended up finding a solution on my own which was `if (UNIX AND NOT APPLE) ... endif ()` to infer Linux as a platform. And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 5):

(I know you're asking about `glibc`, but you really want to know whether `clock_gettime` is present, right?  But nothing in your question is Linux-specific...)

If you want to check for `clock_gettime`, you can use the preprocessor.  If `clock_gettime` is present, then `_POSIX_TIMERS` will be defined.  The `clock_gettime` function is part of an optional POSIX extension ([see spec](http://www.unix.org/version2/whatsnew/realtime.html)), so it is not Linux-specific but not universal either.  Mac OS X does not have `clock_gettime`: it is not declared in any header nor defined in any library.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h> /* for _POSIX_TIMERS definition, if present */

#if _POSIX_TIMERS
...use clock_gettime()...
#else
...use something else...
#endif
```

This doesn't solve the problem that you still have to link with `-lrt` on Linux.  This is typically solved with something like `AC_CHECK_LIB` in Autoconf, I'm sure there's an equivalent in CMake.

From `man 2 clock_gettime`:

> On POSIX systems on which these functions are available, the symbol `_POSIX_TIMERS` is defined in `<unistd.h>` to a value greater than 0. The symbols `_POSIX_MONOTONIC_CLOCK`,  `_POSIX_CPUTIME`, `_POSIX_THREAD_CPUTIME` indicate that `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`, `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID`, `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID` are available. (See also sysconf(3).)

On Darwin you can use the `mach_absolute_time` function if you need a high-resolution monotonic clock.  If you don't need the resolution or monotonicity, you should probably be using `gettimeofday` on both platforms.

Comment: Thanks, Dietrich. I realized this as I was editing my question, since glibc is not really the core of the problem.

Comment: Note that there's also the problem of linking the right library - `clock_gettime` requires `librt` to be explicitly linked on Linux. It might also require some kind of library on OS X, hence the linker errors.

Comment: @bdonlan: Yes, you're right about `-lrt`.  However, there is no `clock_gettime` on OS X.

Comment: @DietrichEpp, interesting - OS X has headers but not libraries for the POSIX timers functions?

Comment: @bdonlan: No, OS X does not have `clock_gettime`: it is not in the headers and it is not in the libraries.  It is not required for POSIX conformance, it is an optional POSIX extension.  Read the quote from the man page again, "On POSIX systems on which these functions are available, the symbol _POSIX_TIMERS is defined".

Comment: @DietrichEpp, fair enough, it's just that the OP's description of a 'linker error' made it sounds like they only had the headers or something

Comment: @bdonlan: Unfortunately, it seems a lot of people still allow their C compilers to generate implicit function declarations.

Comment: @DietrichEpp, that wouldn't explain how it allowed the `CLOCK_*` macros to pass compilation :)

Comment: As of 2008, `clock_gettime` is not optional. It's a mandatory part of POSIX.

Comment: @R..: I've only ever seen Apple claim that Mac OS X is compliant with Single Unix Specification Version 3, a.k.a. POSIX:2001.  It's a sore complaint, given that Linux distros don't even claim POSIX compliance.

Comment: I doubt Mac OSX is conformant to any version of POSIX. For instance it has ugly issues like multiple distinct filenames that are canonically equivalent under Unicode resolving to the same file (which can even lead to security issues).

Comment: @R..: Can you give me a reference to the spec for this?  (Never mind that for a spec of such size, I doubt that *any* operating system is fully compliant to any version.)

Answer (score 0):

There is also built-in CMake macro for checking if symbol exists - [CheckSymbolExists](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#module%3aCheckSymbolExists).